# validating duplicates in data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying show duplicate records in data frame like below but how i can ignore blank or NA because sometimes email column can be blank or NA

```
df4 <- data.frame(emp_id =c("DEV-2962","KTN_2252","ANA2719","ITI_2624","KTN_2252","HRT2921","","KTN2624","DEV2698","ITI2535","DEV2698","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  email = c("akash.dev@abcd.com","rahul.singh@abcd.com","salman.abbas@abcd.com","ram.lal@abcd.com","rahul.singh@abcd.com","prabal.garg@xyz.com","sanu.ali@abcd.com","salman.abbas@abcd.com","","",NA,NA,"giriraj.singh@dkl.com","lokesh.sharma@abcd.com","pooja.pawar@abcd.com","nikita.sharma@abcd.com"))


ID = "emp_id"
Email = "email"

df4 <- df4 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(ID, Email), ~as.integer(duplicated(.)), .names = 'flag_{col}'))
```

Comment: What do you mean "ignore" them? Do you mean drop them? Always treat them as duplicates? Never treat them as duplicates? Something else? Please share your desired output for your sample input.

Comment: for example if two NA's in column email will show duplicate ,same as for emp_id, i dont want to show that . i want to exclude NA's and blank cells for showing duplicates without changing original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert all blank values to `NA` and use an `incomparables` argument in your code:

```
df4 <- df4 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == "", NA, .))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(ID, Email), ~as.integer(duplicated(.,incomparables = NA)), .names = 'flag_{col}'))
```

You can also add arguments to `incomparables`:

```
df4 <- df4 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(ID, Email), ~as.integer(duplicated(.,incomparables = c("", NA))), .names = 'flag_{col}'))
```

Both options give us:

```
     emp_id                  email flag_emp_id flag_email
1  DEV-2962     akash.dev@abcd.com           0          0
2  KTN_2252   rahul.singh@abcd.com           0          0
3   ANA2719  salman.abbas@abcd.com           0          0
4  ITI_2624       ram.lal@abcd.com           0          0
5  KTN_2252   rahul.singh@abcd.com           1          1
6   HRT2921    prabal.garg@xyz.com           0          0
7      <NA>      sanu.ali@abcd.com           0          0
8   KTN2624  salman.abbas@abcd.com           0          1
9   DEV2698                   <NA>           0          0
10  ITI2535                   <NA>           0          0
11  DEV2698                   <NA>           1          0
12  HRT2837                   <NA>           0          0
13  ERV2951  giriraj.singh@dkl.com           0          0
14  KTN2542 lokesh.sharma@abcd.com           0          0
15  ANA2813   pooja.pawar@abcd.com           0          0
16  ITI2210 nikita.sharma@abcd.com           0          0
```

Comment: getting error after some time 
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `     alpucheta` doesn't exist.
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: NodeName = "     alpucheta".